# Sphinx turns apostrophe followed by a "ref" cross-reference into a double quote

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

When I launch the "make html" command, Sphinx replaces my apostrophe by a double quote.

I have tested many solutions, but I don't find a good option.

```py
l':ref:`action`
```

I want to obtain "l'action" but I obtain "l"action".

Comment: What version of Sphinx are you using? I've tried this with v1.8.0 and it seems to give the result that you require?

Comment: My version is Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6)

Comment: I think this has to do with [smartquotes](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-smartquotes). Do you have `language = "fr"` in conf.py?

Comment: Yes, I have `language = "fr"` in my configuration file. When I add `smartquotes = False`, it works !! Thanks a lot !